# Pythonでforループを使ってDataFrameを作成すると、異なる変数が全て同じ結果になる。

Tags: python, python3, pandas, numpy

Pythonとpandasの以下のプログラムに関する質問です。

以下の6つの変数は異なる期間とデータを持つ、index が datetimeindex の Series です。
1~3の違いは期間が異なり、aとbはデータが異なります。

season_a1
season_b1

season_a2
season_b2

season_a3
season_b3

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

#結果を格納するDataFrame
result_df1 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
result_df2 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
result_df3 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))


for year in range(2000, 2004):

    if str(year) in season_b1.index:
        a1 = season_a1[str(year)].index.hour.value_counts().sort_index()
        b1 = season_b1[str(year)].index.hour.value_counts().sort_index()
        result_df1['A' + str(year)] = a1
        result_df1['B' + str(year)] = b1
# 1

    if str(year) in season_b2.index:
        a2 = season_a2[str(year)].index.hour.value_counts().sort_index()
        b2 = season_b2[str(year)].index.hour.value_counts().sort_index()
        result_df2['A' + str(year)] = a2
        result_df2['B' + str(year)] = b2
# 2

    if str(year) in season_b3.index:
        a3 = season_a3[str(year)].index.hour.value_counts().sort_index()
        b3 = season_b3[str(year)].index.hour.value_counts().sort_index()
        result_df3['A' + str(year)] = a3
        result_df3['B' + str(year)] = b3
# 3

result_df1.to_csv(path1)
result_df2.to_csv(path2)
result_df3.to_csv(path3)
```

単純にvalue_counts()で集計した結果の

a1, b1　は、　result_df1　に。
a2, b2　は、　result_df2　に。
a3, b3　は、　result_df3　に。

列として追加していき、 csvファイルとして出力するだけです。

欲しい結果としては、result_df1~3 の結果が全て異なるものになって欲しいのですが、
それぞれ元となるデータも変数名も異なるのに、
出力される結果が全て result_df3 の内容と同じになってしまいます。

確認として、# 1~3 の部分で result_df1~3 の内容を print() してみたのですが、
1回目のループの # 2 のところで既に result_df1 が result_df2 と同じになっていて
 # 3 のところでは result_df1 , result_df2 も result_df3 と同じになっています。

初歩的なミスだとは思うのですが、解決できません。
申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: season_xx のデータがないと答えられなそうです。仮のデータでもよいので、ここに掲載してもよい最小の再現可能なコード＆データを掲載してください。コピペで検証できるコードになっていると回答も早いと思います。

Comment: @Takayuki SHIMIZUKAWA　さん コメントありがとうございます。
一点記載ミス（本文２行目）がありましたので修正しました。

season_xx の中身は、Seriesとなっており、
.index.hour.value_counts() で DatetimeIndex の 時間（hour）だけの配列を作り、その時間の数字の個数をカウントしているだけになります。 
なお、そのSeriesに入っている値は 10 または 11 の数字のみになります。
     
ちなみにですが、列の追加方法を
    result_df['A' + str(year)] = a
という書き方ではなく、
    result_df = pd.concat([result_df, a, b], axis=1) 
にすると、変数の中身が同じになるという現象は起こりません。

Answer (score 0):

コメントにもあるように再現可能な最小限のコードがないと正確な回答をするのは難しいですが、例えば以下の部分で

```
result_df1 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
result_df2 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
result_df3 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
```

次のようになっていると、同じような現象が起こると思います。

```
result_df1 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
result_df2 = result_df1
result_df3 = result_df1
```

初期化時にこのようにしてしまうと、Pythonは参照を代入するのでresult_dfはすべて同一の値を持ちます。したがってすべて最後に代入したresult_df3の値になります。

Comment: T. Ogawa　さん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
私もはじめその可能性を疑いテストしてみたのですが、例えば、

    df1 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
    df2 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))
    df3 = DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 24))

と変数を初期化し、いずれかの変数に列を追加したのちに他の変数を確認してもindexのみの空のDataFrameのままになっています。
よってその可能性はないものと判断しております。